# Sending other elements ID while calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, element

Hello I am developing a jQuery mobile app and Here is the situation

```
      <script>
            function showPanel(info) {

                alert(info.id);

            }
        </script>

<div data-role="footer" id="footer_button" onclick="showPanel(this);">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>
</div>

<div id="footerhigher1"></div>
```

Now in this code `onclick` event of the first div I am passing `this` from which I am extracting the id of the first `div`. Now I want to pass the Id of second `div` whose `Id` is **footerhigher1** also How can I deal with it.

I have multiple combination like these in single page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  <script>
        function showPanel(idval) {

            alert($(idval).id);

        }
    </script>

<div data-role="footer" id="footer_button" onclick="showPanel('footerhigher1');">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>
</div>

<div id="footerhigher1"></div>
```

**or**

---

### JsFiddle Demo

just modify the script like this, it will give you next div element

```
  <script>
        function showPanel(idval) {

            alert($(info).next().attr('id'));

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: But here we have to explicitly keep the id in onclick="showPanel('footerhigher1');"

Cant we pass the this object of the second div

Comment: @user2164685 - check the or code you can do this "$(info).next().arrt('id')"